# How to count the number of files in a directory?

Tags: php, laravel-5

I would like to know how to count the number of files in a directory using Laravel 5.2:

```
$folderPath="upload/";
$countFile=0;
$totalFiles=glob($folderPath."*");
if($totalFiles){
    $countFile=count($totalFiles);
}
print_r($countFile);
```

this is not working for me.

Comment: Try it with this : `$folderPath=public_path('upload');` !!

Answer (score 5):

You can count the number of files in a directory using `files` or `allFiles`, as per the 5.6 [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/filesystem#directories) (though, this feature as been around since 5.0 and your question was specifically regarding 5.2).

The difference between `files` and `allFiles` is that `allFiles` will recursively search sub-directories unlike `files`. Again, as per the documentation:

> The files method returns an array of all of the files in a given directory. If you would like to retrieve a list of all files within a given directory including all sub-directories, you may use the  allFiles method:

and the example code that was provided:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;

$files = Storage::files($directory);

$files = Storage::allFiles($directory);
```

**Note:** This answer has been provided as a more thorough version of an older answer (which pointed me in the right direction, however I personally wanted to confirm that it still worked) with linked documentation / code in the actual answer from the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

I am no sure about L5.2, but I am sure you can use the Storage facade for that

`$files = Storage::files($directoryPath);`

This will return all files and you can count it directly?

Or use `allFiles()` if you want it recursively.